# Google App Engine ModuleHostname: not an App Engine context

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to discover other deployed services on the App Engine. Something like [this](https://billglover.me/2018/01/06/google-app-engine-service-discovery/) article suggests.

This is how my code looks like:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "google.golang.org/appengine"
)

func ServiceHostname(serviceName string, r *http.Request) (string, error) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    hostname, err := appengine.ModuleHostname(ctx, serviceName, "", "")
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("unable to find service %s: %v", serviceName, err)
    }
    return hostname, nil
}
```

I am calling this function in a regular http handler. The error I've got is: `not an App Engine context`.

The only difference in between my code and the referenced article is in app engine go version. I am using the new `go111` where he's using `go1` runtime.

Do you know how to overcome the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. You need to call `appengine.Main()` in your main file even though it shouldn't be necessary to do in the new `go111` runtime.

So the code in question stays the same, you need to register your handlers same as in `go1.9` runtime.

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/serveurl", handle)
    appengine.Main()
}
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine-go/ZcASFMWJKpE/7iwGirNiBgAJ

It's alo mentioned in [Writing a main package](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences#writing_a_main_package):

> - Or, if your service is using the `google.golang.org/appengine` package, include a call to `appengine.Main()`.

Answer (score 1):

The article you referenced was written with the 1st generation standard environment in mind, the 2nd generation (go111) wasn't [released](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/release-notes#october_10_2018) at that time:

> October 10, 2018
>
> Go runtime notes
>
> The [Go 1.11 runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111) for the App Engine standard environment is
>   now in beta. A migration guide for [moving apps from Go 1.9 to Go
>   1.11](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences) is available.

The differences between the two generations are significant (for all languages, not only for go). In the [Migrating from the App Engine Go SDK (Optional)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences#migrating-appengine-sdk) section of the migration guide I noticed:

> - Use [`request.Context()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/?#Request.Context) or your preferred context instead of using [`appengine.NewContext`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/reference#NewContext).

Which *might* be related to your error. But I'm not actually a go user, this is just a theory :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and good catch, but it didn't solve my issue. I've tried to use regular context as article advice but the error stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand this error is returned when your AppEngine application has the runtime set to go111 and the application  imports any of the "google.golang.org/appengine" packages like log, urlfetch, memcache, etc. but the application doesn’t call the “appengine.Main” method.

Therefore you can choose either implementation below:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "google.golang.org/appengine"
)

func init() {
    // register handlers
    http.HandleFunc(“/“, indexHandler)

    appengine.Main()
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
.......handle the request.......
}

func ServiceHostname(serviceName string, r *http.Request) (string, error) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    hostname, err := appengine.ModuleHostname(ctx, serviceName, "", "")
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("unable to find service %s: %v", serviceName, err)
    }
    return hostname, nil
}
```

Or abandon all appengine packages:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    “log”
    "net/http"
    “os”
)

func main() {
    port := os.Getenv(“PORT”)
    if port == “” {
        port = “8080”
    }

    http.HandleFunc(“/“, indexHandler)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(“:”+port, Nil)
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()
.....handle request....
}
```