# Code displaying an URL rather than the reponse of the request GCP with Go

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console, google-app-engine-golang

I'm having hard times trying to display the result of a direction request in Google Cloud Platform. This is what I have tried:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "context"
    "io/ioutil"
    "google.golang.org/appengine"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/urlfetch"
)

const directionAPIKey = "MyAppKey"
const directionURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%s&destination=%s&mode=%s&key=%s"

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    direction, err := fetchDirection(ctx, r.FormValue("origin"), r.FormValue("destination"), r.FormValue("mode"))
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    w.Write(direction)
}

func fetchDirection(ctx context.Context, origin string, destination string, mode string) ([]byte, error) {
    client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)
    resp, err := client.Get(fmt.Sprintf(directionURL, origin, destination, mode, directionAPIKey))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    return ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
}
```

I got my app successfully deployed, however, the result of the above code is:

```
Get https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=&destination=&mode=&key=APIKey not an App Engine context
```

Rather than the result of the request. This is an **[image](https://i.ibb.co/xGrtXG3/Capture.jpg)** from the browser. How can I get the desired result and not only that URL? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/appengine/issues/167#issuecomment-432667452

Comment: I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801551/google-app-engine-modulehostname-not-an-app-engine-context) that the issue "not an App Engine context" is returned when your AppEngine application has the runtime set to go111 and the application imports any of the "google.golang.org/appengine" packages but the application doesn’t call the “appengine.Main” method  
**func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    appengine.Main()
}** so could you please try it ans share the result?

Comment: @AndieVanille Yep, downgraded the version from 112 to 111 and added the call to `appengine.Main()` and everything worked fine. I was struggling for days now. I think you should add it as an answer as it solved my entire problem. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @AsenValchev Indeed that was my problem and that solution worked for me.

Comment: @LisDya Glad to hear that the issue has been resolved :) !!!!! I added the answer and I will appreciate if you mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801551/google-app-engine-modulehostname-not-an-app-engine-context) that the issue "not an App Engine context" is returned when your AppEngine application has the runtime set to go111 and the application imports any of the "google.golang.org/appengine" packages but the application doesn’t call the “appengine.Main”

```
method func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    appengine.Main()
}
```